# Specs in Rails don't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

I have rspec with some specs but after some migrations the specs don't start. I execute

```
bundle exec rake spec
```

And the command with the correct Ruby version and some specs I have are shown:

```
/Users/jose/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/controllers/apps_controller_spec.rb ./spec/integration/users_spec.rb
```

But after that, nothing is shown. I've tried with Guard too, but I get the same result.

I've rollback to previous migrations but nothing happens.

Any solutions or workarounds?

P.S. This is my gemfile -> https://gist.github.com/4258413

Comment: No, actually I don't see nothing in the output apart from that :/

Comment: If I check the log of test I see some queries, always the same, of 2 models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved.

I was including all the files under lib in spec_helper.rb:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("lib/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

The problem was that in that directory I had a daemon too, so something like this was executed every time.

```
$running = true
Signal.trap("TERM") do 
  $running = false
end

while($running) do
  # do things
  sleep 10
end
```

Sorry for a silly question.